# How to emit LDC_I8 for a ulong.Parse call?

Tags: c#, reflection.emit, il

I'm having an issue with emitting IL to set a uint64 property value.  Below is some minimal code to reproduce the issue.

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Reflection.Emit;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      AssemblyBuilder assemblyBuilder = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(
        new AssemblyName("test"), AssemblyBuilderAccess.RunAndSave);
      ModuleBuilder m_moduleBuilder = assemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicModule("test.dll",
        "test.dll");
      TypeBuilder typeBuilder = m_moduleBuilder.DefineType("Class1",
        TypeAttributes.Public |
        TypeAttributes.Class |
        TypeAttributes.AutoClass |
        TypeAttributes.AnsiClass |
        TypeAttributes.BeforeFieldInit |
        TypeAttributes.AutoLayout, null);

      FieldBuilder fieldBuilder = typeBuilder.DefineField("m_prop1",
          typeof(ulong), FieldAttributes.Private);

      MethodBuilder getMethodBuilder = typeBuilder.DefineMethod(
        "get_prop1",
        MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.SpecialName |
        MethodAttributes.HideBySig,
        typeof(ulong), Type.EmptyTypes);
      ILGenerator getIlGen = getMethodBuilder.GetILGenerator();
      getIlGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
      getIlGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, fieldBuilder);
      getIlGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

      MethodBuilder setMethodBuilder = typeBuilder.DefineMethod(
        "set_prop1",
        MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.SpecialName |
        MethodAttributes.HideBySig,
        null, new[] { typeof(ulong) });
      ILGenerator setIlGen = setMethodBuilder.GetILGenerator();
      setIlGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
      setIlGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
      setIlGen.Emit(OpCodes.Stfld, fieldBuilder);
      setIlGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

      PropertyBuilder propertyBuilder = typeBuilder.DefineProperty(
        "prop1", PropertyAttributes.HasDefault, typeof(ulong),
        null);
      propertyBuilder.SetGetMethod(getMethodBuilder);
      propertyBuilder.SetSetMethod(setMethodBuilder);

      ConstructorBuilder constructorBuilder =
        typeBuilder.DefineConstructor(MethodAttributes.Public,
        CallingConventions.Standard, Type.EmptyTypes);
      ILGenerator ilGenerator = constructorBuilder.GetILGenerator();
      ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
      ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Call,
        typeBuilder.BaseType.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes));
      ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
      ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I8, ulong.Parse("0"));
      ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Call, propertyBuilder.GetSetMethod());
      ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

      Type class1Type = typeBuilder.CreateType();

      assemblyBuilder.Save("test.dll");
    }
  }
}
```

If you run peverify on the created .dll you get the following:

```
[IL]: Error: [C:\code\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\bin\Debug\test.dl
 : Class1::.ctor][offset 0x00000010] Unrecognized local variable number.
1 Error(s) Verifying test.dll
```

If you dissassemble the constructor it looks like follows:

```
.method public specialname rtspecialname 
        instance void  .ctor() cil managed
{
  // Code size       18 (0x12)
  .maxstack  4
  IL_0000:  ldarg.0
  IL_0001:  call       instance void [mscorlib]System.Object::.ctor()
  IL_0006:  ldarg.0
  IL_0007:  ldc.i8     0x22800000000
  IL_0010:  ldloc.0
  IL_0011:  ret
} // end of method Class1::.ctor
```

So why is `ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I8, ulong.Parse("0"));` being turned into
`IL_0007:  ldc.i8     0x22800000000` and what happened to the property set call?

Changing ulong.Parse to long.Parse gets it to create an assembly without these errors but then the long.Parse will crash if I feed it a value greater than long.MaxValue.

Comment: According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x3aeheba.aspx `Emit` does not know anything about `ulong` as a second parameter (only `Int64` which is signed)... see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.ldc_i8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) too - MSDN says explicitely "signed long"...

Comment: Not an answer, but the usual way to denote a numeric literal of type `ulong` in C# is `0ul`, so you could use `ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I8, 0ul);`. Edit: But see answer by Ian Griffith on what overload of `Emit` is actually called. An `ulong` converts to `float` implicitly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That particular call to `Emit` ends up using the overload that accepts a `float`, due to the lack of a `ulong`-aware overload, as you've discovered since posting your original question. The funny-looking constant you see in ILDASM is mainly because that overload will only have emitted four bytes for the 0 value, but an 8 byte constant was expected, so it interpreted the following opcodes as the higher order bytes of the constant (which also explains why the property accessor call was apparently replaced with a completely different opcode).

Comment: The property accessor didn't vanish completely. It seems it was replaced by `ldloc.0`, precisely because of the byte number mismatch.

Comment: Solution could be to use overload that takes a signed `long`, so `ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I8, 0L);`. Edit:  An `ulong` converts to `float` implicitly.

Comment: @svick good point - I've edited my post to take this into account. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to use the unchecked keyword to convert the ulong to a long to make the emit operation happy.

```
  ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I8, unchecked((long)ulong.Parse("0")));
```

Comment: You shouldn't need that `unchecked` there, unless you changed the default from unchecked to checked in project properties.

Comment: I agree. In this case, the type cast without the unchecked is enough.  I didn't try that because I saw that long val = (long)0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF; will not compile. However, it will coerce a ulong to a long if instead of a literal value you are typecasting a ulong variable or method return value.  Anyone else find that inconsistency a bit confusing? I will accept Ian's answer for explaining why the IL looks the way it does. Thank you everyone for your responses!

Comment: Yeah, for casting of literals, the default is checked. I think that makes sense: if the compiler is sure overflow will happen, it's good that it tells you about it by reporting an error. But inconsistency certainly is confusing if you don't know about it.